# Moving data from Cloudera to Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, cloudera, amazon-emr, bigdata

I have data on CDH hdfs and I want to move it to Amazon S3 bucket, so I can run the code on AWS EMR instead of CDH.
How can I move it securely and fast?

Can I do it with s3a command or any other efficient way to do it?

Comment: You can use `aws s3 cp` to copy any file to an S3 bucket.

Comment: I tried using aws S3 cp but after sometime copying stopped.

Comment: If transfer was interrupted for some reason, you can always use `aws s3 sync` instead.

Comment: aws s3 cp will not work as I am copy file from hdfs to S3, not local file.
since I am copying data from CDH to Amazon S3, I need to pass s3 access key and secret key.
I tried to run command:
hdfs dfs -cp <hdfs_path> s3n://<s3_access_key>:<s3_secret_key>@<s3_location_with_bucket_name>

but its not working. It gives me "both source file listing and source paths present".

Comment: But you can always mount HDFS filesystem, right? https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/MountableHDFS

Comment: Sure, but if I mount the HDFS filesystem, the network speed will get decreased, and I have to move 100TB of data

Answer (score 0):

I use hdfs distcp to copy data from S3 to hdfs. It also supports vice versa so should work in your case as well.
Since it uses map reduce internally and does parallel processing its pretty fast. I created a script for running this command for an array of dates and then run it using nohup in background mode.
Syntax of command is :

```
hadoop distcp -Dfs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId=$S3NKEYID -      Dfs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey=$S3NKEY s3n://$COPYFROMENV/$TABLE_PATH/$TABLE/$PARTITION_PATH hdfs://$COPYTOENV/$TABLE_PATH/$TABLE/
```

Comment: I already tried this command, it gives me.
Error tools.distcp.Distcp: Invalid refused
java.net.connectException: Connection refused.

Any workaround this?

Comment: This usually happens when the datanode on which you are running the command cannot access S3. You need to ensure that s3 is accessible from the node where you are running this command.